# Make promise wait until element NOT exists

Tags: javascript, promise

I found a promise definition [here](https://paul.kinlan.me/waiting-for-an-element-to-be-created/) that waits until an element exists in the DOM:

```js
function waitForElement(selector) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var element = document.querySelector(selector);

    if(element) {
      resolve(element);
      return;
    }

    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
      mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        var nodes = Array.from(mutation.addedNodes);
        for(var node of nodes) {
          if(node.matches && node.matches(selector)) {
            observer.disconnect();
            resolve(node);
            return;
          }
        };
      });
    });

    observer.observe(document.documentElement, { childList: true, subtree: true });
  });
}
```

I need the **reverse** promise also for an element like `LINK` that does not have any `onRemoved` event. In other words, how can I have a promise that resolves as soon as an element is removed from DOM!?

Comment: What do you mean by *for an element like LINK that does not have any onRemoved event*?

Comment: ` for an element like LINK` Huh? `<link>`?

Comment: Also, is this element that will be removed dynamically attached to the DOM?

Comment: Yes exactly. For example for favicon link element.

Comment: So, did you try to adapt the `MutationObserver` code that you found?

Comment: It will be removed by the UI5 framework, I want to observe the remove event and do some actions as soon as it has been removed from DOM.

Comment: @Bergi The question is how can I use `MutationObserver` for observing the remove event?

Comment: @MahdiJ.Ansari Did you take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord?

Comment: Would probably be a lot cleaner/reliable to check why your framework removes this element, and check if there is an event that is fired at the same time on which you can subscribe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the parent of the element you want to check for is persistent, and the element you want to check for is removed from the parent (eg, the parent itself isn't removed), attach an observer to the parent and check to see if any of its `removedNodes` match the element you want to observe:

```js
const prom = new Promise((resolve) => {
  new MutationObserver((mutations, observer) => {
    for (const mutation of mutations) {
      for (const removedNode of mutation.removedNodes) {
        if (removedNode.id === 'button') {
          observer.disconnect();
          resolve();
        }
      }
    }
  })
    .observe(outer, { childList: true });
});

button.addEventListener('click', () => button.remove());

prom.then(() => {
  console.log('promise resolved');
});
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <button id="button">click</button>
</div>
```

If one of the element-to-be-removed's *parents* may be removed instead, you'll have to attach the listener to an ancestor, not just the immediate parent, and watch for if any of the removed nodes are any of the elements in the chain to the node you're interested in.

A less elegant solution would be to poll with `setInterval`:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const prom = new Promise((resolve) => {
  const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    if (!button.isConnected) {
      resolve();
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
  }, 50);
});

button.addEventListener('click', () => button.remove());

prom.then(() => {
  console.log('promise resolved');
});
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <button>click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you make your function more general that we pass the selector to the promise?

Comment: @MahdiJ.Ansari Why would you do that? The element already exists currently, right? So just pass `document.querySelector(theSelector)` for the element

Comment: You could also attach a subtree observer to `document.body`, and on every callback, check if `document.body.contains(nodeToWatch)`

Comment: Yes, But I meant it would be worthwhile if you make your solution more general that works based on selector. Also you made the solution based on element `id`? What when the element does not have id?

Comment: @MahdiJ.Ansari That's just an example of how you'd look for an element. Feel free to substitute that with whatever logic you need - you can use `querySelector`, or check to see if the node's `textContent` is something, etc. Any sort of test you can think of to use to check an element outside an observer, you can also put that test inside the observer.

Comment: @CertainPerformance What is the `outer`? Where do you define it?

Comment: @MahdiJ.Ansari That's the parent of the element you want to observe. You can select it any way you want, whether by `querySelector`, or by finding the element to observe and accessing its `parentElement`, etc. It's just an example to show how Promises can work with MutationObserver to watch for a removed element. If you have a more specific problem with selecting the elements, you can edit that information into your question.