# Return true on MutationObserver

Tags: javascript, dom, return, dom-manipulation, mutation-observers

I need to `return true` from my code below.  However, I am struggling to `return` any value from MutationObserver().

Where I have console.logged "Button appears" is where I want to `return true`, but I can't seem to get true to return.

To confirm, my code does work and `console.log("Holidays button displayed...")` is run, when my conditions are met.  But I must find a way to return **true**.

```
//WAIT FOR BUTTON FUNCTION
function waitForElement(className, callBack){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        var element = document.querySelector(className);
        if(element) {
            callBack(className, element);
        } else {
            waitForElement(className, callBack);
        }
    },1000)
};

let value = '';

// MUTATION OBSERVER
let observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    for (let i = 0; i < mutations.length; i++) {
        if (mutations[i].oldValue === "button ng-hide") {
            console.log("Button displayed...");
            return true;

            // value = true;
            // return value;
        };
    };
});

// WAIT FOR 
waitForElement(`[search-model="pod"]`,function(){
    let target = document.querySelector('[search-model="pod"]"]');
    observer.observe(target, { attributes : true, attributeOldValue: true, subtree: true});
});
```

What's the best way to return true/false in MutationObserver?  Any pointers would be helpful!

I've also tried with promises, but this doesn't seem to work, as button I'm watching can appear and reappear in the DOM intermittently.  And I think this promise with promises will only return true the first time?  (Nott all times?)

```
function waitForElement(selector) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var element = document.querySelector(selector);

        if(element) {
            var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
                for (let i = 0; i < mutations.length; i++) {
                    if (mutations[i].oldValue === "button ng-hide") {
                        console.log("Holidays button displayed...");
                        resolve();
                        return;
                    };
                };
              });
              let target = document.querySelector('[search-model="pod"]');
              observer.observe(target, { childList: true, attributes : true, attributeOldValue: true, subtree: true});
        };

    });
  };
  waitForElement(`[search-model="pod"]`).then(function(element) {
    console.log("Element Added", element);
    return true;
});
```

Comment: You can't return from the callback and expect that value to be returned by `MutationObserver`. You need promises here.

Comment: I noticed you’re asking for the subTree but not the childList.

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61359599/make-promise-wait-until-element-not-exists help?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv - Hey Sergiu, this is really helpful thank you. Looks like I can combine mutation observer with promises and return a value this way?  I'll try and recreate this, using the example you've given me. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @SergiuParaschiv - I've had a go with promies, but would this approach work, if I want to watch a button, which appears and disappears multiple times?  I've updated my code above, but woudln't a promise only resolves the first time?  I basically need to fire true every time the button reappears...

Comment: That indeed is a problem, and probably the reason `MutationObserver` uses a callback (once resolved a promise's then callback is always called with the first resolved value). You can probably do the same: ditch the promise and instead pass a callback function to `waitForElement`. I'm not sure what the end result should be though, why do you need to `return true` somewhere? Is it enough if `waitForElement` calls a function every time the button is added?

Comment: Thanks at @SergiuParaschiv. I’ll give this a go. The reason why I need to return true, every time the button appears, is because I’m creating an AB Test in a UI tool called Google Optimize 360.  And I need my test to fire every time the button appears. However, the tool, Google Optimize, will only trigger the test, if I “return” a value. So I have to return something. I’ll give the function a go. Thank you